# MapKit Custom Annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit, ios6

I have some questinos regarding iOS6 mapkit. I tried to create [a simple application that shows my current location and adds custom annotations to my MapView control](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jg8Ju1jtSA). This is my code:

```
@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>{}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D cordinate;

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) t coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
@implementation MapViewAnnotation
@synthesize title;
@synthesize coordinate;
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) t coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    self = [super init];
    self.title = t;
    self.coordinate = c;
    return self;
}
@end
```

And this is `UIViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>{}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

And the `.main` file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
@interface ViewController () @end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView, locationManager;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = 37.78608;
    location.longitude = -122.405398;

    MapViewAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store location" coordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
}
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 250, 250);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
@end
```

It displays my current location successfully, but when I use this line in viewDidLoad:

```
MapViewAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store location" coordinate:location];
```

I get this exception:

```
MapKitDemo[3426:c07] -[MapViewAnnotation setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8551ae0
2012-10-03 16:19:23.070 MapKitDemo[3426:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MapViewAnnotation setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8551ae0'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is the `cordinate` property really spelled with one `o` in the actual code or is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: That was my mistake, `corinate`. You can share your answer and then I accept it.

Comment: The existing answers are sufficient (with the spelling correction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the property self.coordinate in the `-initWithTitle:coordinate:` method of your subclass, this means that the coordinate is being set using the property as opposed to the iVar, since this property is set to `readonly`, you are getting this error and probably crash...

You must access the iVar directly like so:

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"
@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title = _title, coordinate = _coordinate    

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) t coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _title = t;
        _coordinate = c;
        // self.coordinate = c /* !This is readonly ! */
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Notice I also changed the `@synthesize` (which isn't required anymore - this is done automatically as of Xcode 4.5 I believe? Maybe an earlier version). Also note that I did a condition in your init, you should do this it will make sure you don't try to et properties/iVars on nil in the case that `[super init]` failed to initialise your object.

Comment: Good point @Daniel, +1 for your help. it is completely worked with `readonly`

Comment: It's a common mistake, as a rule I always set my iVars directly in the init method rather then use the properties. Glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

coordinate is a readonly property. You can't use the setter for it. Use the ivar or make it read/write.

Comment: I made it readwrite, but I got the same error. what do you mean by ivar? sorry I am new in iOS.

Comment: @Ali if you update the code in Xcode then update it here as well. It makes it harder to figure out the answer if have to read the comments to find out the latest code listing.

Comment: @J2theC, I found my mistake, but your point was also useful, thanks. +1 for that. I can also use the @Daniel approach with `readonly`.

Comment: @SnowCrash, take a look on Daniel answer. I don't need to change anything. I just need to fix my mistake that Anna mentioned.